# Mysql 1406 Data too long for column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a string containing more than 600 characters, where I want to Insert it in a column `VARCHAR (255)` column
 I tested on two different databases:

1. For a `mysql 5.7.31-34-log` database, I ran into this exception: 
   **SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'name' at row 1"**

- I dumped the **sql_mode** for each database and this the result:

> ["@@sql_mode"]=>
> string(40) "STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

2. On the other hand for a `mysql 5.7.19` database, the string is well registered into my database, but with a warning message:
   **Level Code    Message 

   Warning 1265    Data truncated for column 'name' at row 1**

- sql_mode:

> ["@@sql_mode"]=>
> string(0) ""

I would be grateful if someone could explain to me it is a good practice to disable strict mode, and does truncate remove a part of the string if exceeded ?

Comment: `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` causes data truncate to be an error whereas with this mode disabled the truncation generates warning only.

Comment: Is it a good practice to disable strict mode, and does truncate remove a part of the string if exceeded ?

Comment: *Is it a good practice to disable strict mode* No. Good practice is to check/adjust data before storing. Error is a detection that the above operation wwas performed wrongly, and it does not allow to save wrong data.

Comment: Does truncating gonna remove a part of the string ?

Comment: o_O of course !

Comment: Truncate to 255 characters ?, because I checked and my string Is well inserted without any truncate when I just disable STRICT mode.

Comment: *my string Is well inserted without any truncate* I don't believe. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=82ffed0a1a4948e6f0ca22278d3212eb Check actual column definition by SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Comment: disable strict mode is not recommended. It prevents us from wrong operations. so that we can double sure what we are storing and where query is breaking.

Comment: 'The CHAR and VARCHAR types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store. For example, CHAR(30) can hold up to 30 characters.; - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html

Answer (score 1):

you cannot store 600 character in varchar(255) since It's allowing only 255 character.dependingvon your configuration data will be rejected or truncated after 255 character.
The version of MySql you are using allow way more that 255 for varchar data type. please alter the column to extend the length. you may use varchar(600) for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can insert a 600 long string into a 255 long column.
Change your VARCHAR(255) by TEXT and it will be ok.

Comment: Thank, but I need an explanation about the best practice, not a quick solution